# Firefox does no longer use the configured Bluetooth Headset in Ubuntu 22.04.1

Tags: sound, firefox, bluetooth

I'm using Firefox 104.0.2 and it uses the normal audio instead of the bluetooth headset I configured in the settings. This stopped working a few days ago. I also tried Firefox via flatpack (org.mozilla.firefox) and it also does not work.

Other native applications and also snap applications like chromium (version 105.0.5195.102) work and use the configured headset, so it seems to be a Firefox bug.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working. Not sure if this is a permanent solution but I just started `pavucontrol` and configured Firefox to switch to the headset output.